# omniauth-office365 gem permission error from Outlook rest API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth, office365api

Hello All implementing basic office 365 integration to contacts from a rails application.  I have already connected with google using omniauth-google-oauth2 and google-api-client.  I am following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/ruby-tutorial for app setup and am using the strategy omniauth-office365 as I did previously.  It appears I have all setup right but when I authenticate I get the following error :
[image]

I have my settings in accordance to the docs, I dont know what I am missing..

The basic usage at this moment is just to authenticate which I have added the code below to omniauth.rb:

`

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
     provider :office365, '$myid', '$mykey',
           {:scope => 'mail.read, User.read, profile,openid'}
end
```

I added a route to my routes.rb:

```
  get 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'contacts#contact_integrations'

  get 'auth/failure', to: redirect('/')
```

In my controller I added :

```
  def contact_integrations
    access_token = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
  end
```

In a view I added a link to :

```
<%= link_to 'Outlook', "/auth/office365" %>
```

I did the above method with google and it worked fine, of course I added more code to get what I needed from the API but the upfront authentication was obtained.  If I click the link I get the expected login/authenticate screens from office365, but it returns the permissions error shown in the image even though it is set to be able to access all accounts.

Comment: Office 365 was down world wide. If your setup was previously working it could be related to that.

https://www.nzherald.co.nz/business/news/article.cfm?c_id=3&objectid=12286870

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)".

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with the gem strategy omniauth-office365.  I followed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/ruby?tutorial-step=3 and added that strategy and was able to authenticate..